# QGIS: Create custom CRS that divides current co-ordinates by 1000

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a CAD dataset which I have converted to shapefiles for use in QGIS, but the co-ordinates are in millimetres, not metres. So instead of 409234,5955278, they are mapped as 409234099,5955278132. The CRS should be EPSG:7855 GDA2020/MGA Zone 55.

I'm not familiar with the custom CRS tool in QGIS, and was wondering if it was possible to create a Custom CRS that simply divides the X,Y co-ords by 1000 to get them into the right projection? Or do I have to get my hands dirty with Python which I am also unfamiliar with?

Comment: Mapping geographic features in millimeters is less than ideal. Far better to use a standardized CRS. So even if you create a custom CRS, it will just be for a one-time transformation to a standard one. Either way, you'll likely get your hands dirty.

Comment: Of what is your data set comprised? Points, lines, polygons? This shouldn't be a QGIS problem. It's a CAD problem. If your data is points, it's an Excel problem.

Comment: If you have access to CAD software it will be simpler to change the drawing unit to meter before using it with QGIS

Comment: I can think of many other ways of doing this but being able to have a custom CRS would be handy, I would often prefer not to alter a CAD Input unless I have to so a custom CRS in meters would be useful

Comment: And thanks to everyone else's comments as well. Appreciate the input.

Comment: @Sethinacan I tried :) but couldn't get a custom CRS to work. Then I thought that this was probably a sort of [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and the OP just wanted the data in the right place and wouldn't be too concerned if a different way of doing so was proposed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than messing around making a custom CRS, if you don't mind creating a new layer, you can apply a transform that scales the geometry by 0.001 using the Processing->Vector Geometry->[Affine transform](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaffinetransform) tool.

Given your example point, imported as is (still in mm) using EPSG:7855 (GDA2020/MGA zone 55). Running the Affine transform tool with a 0.001 x and y scale factor places the point in Benalla, Vic:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Legendary!! Thanks so much for this answer, and I love learning new things about QGIS. It worked perfectly!!